# Extract email and phone number

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I used this code:

```
#! python3
import pyperclip, re

#Regex for phone number
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''

(
# phone number
('+1')?
(\s)?
((\d\d\d) | (\ (\d\d\d)))?  #area code optional
(\s|-) # first separator
\d\d\d # first 3 digits
- # Separator
\d\d\d\d # last 4 digits
)
''', re.VERBOSE)

#email
emailRegex = re.compile (r'''
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+ # name part
@ # @ symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+ # domain part
''', re.VERBOSE)

# text off the clipbord
text = pyperclip.paste()

# Extract the email / phone from text
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text)
extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall(text)

allPhoneNumbers = []
for phoneNumber in extractedPhone:
    allPhoneNumbers.append(phoneNumber[0])

#print (allPhoneNumbers)
#print (extractedEmail)

# Copy the extracted email/phone to the clipbord
results = '\n'.join(allPhoneNumbers) + '\n'.join(extractedEmail)
pyperclip.copy(results)
```

and I tried to removed from this list:

```
+1 (786) 665-5397, +1 (786) 773-7145, +1 (786) 804-8869, +1 (786) 806-5097, +1 (786) 856-7950, +1 (786) 862-2875, +1 (786) 915-7830, +1 (786) 991-4304, +1 (857) 334-1162, +1 (862) 944-0090, +1 (863) 307-5291, +1 (914) 826-4343, +1 (918) 992-1382, +1 (954) 226-7037,
```

It doesn't print the area code. I spend few hours trying to find the problem, but no success. I think it's because the `+1`. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Please use the code formatting mechanisms, your Python is pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by another answer, whitespace in a pattern is significant in RegEx. You can make RegEx ignore your whitespace, by prefixing your pattern with `(?x)`.

I'm not entirely sure, what your aim with `((\d\d\d) | (\ (\d\d\d)))` is. Shouldn't you need to escape your parenthesis instead? i.e. just `(\(\d\d\d\))` would be sufficient? (*I'm not American, so unsure if I'm missing something*).

Thus the final pattern, would look something like this:

```regex
(?x)(
# phone number
(\+1)?
(\s)?
(\(\d\d\d\))?  #area code optional
(\s|-) # first separator
\d\d\d # first 3 digits
- # Separator
\d\d\d\d # last 4 digits
)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kGWu8P/1)

Assuming you don't need to capture all the various whitespace, then you can additionally turn `(\s)?` into `\s?` or `\s*` if you want to allow more space. You can also change `(\s|-)` into `(?:\s|-)`, where `?:` tells RegEx that it's a "non-capturing group".

```regex
(?x)(
# phone number
(\+1)?
\s*
(\(\d\d\d\))?  #area code optional
(?:\s|-) # first separator
\d\d\d # first 3 digits
- # Separator
\d\d\d\d # last 4 digits
)
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, remove the white spaces around the bar in `"(\d\d\d) | (\ (\d\d\d))"`. Regex is not space-agnostic. If you have a space in the pattern, you must have it in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone numbers are always formatted as in your example you can easily remove the first 3 characters, parenthesis and minus symbols as follows:

```
phoneNumber = '+1 (347) 442-7698'
re.sub('[\(\)\s\-]', '', phoneNumber[3:])
```

Which gives you:

```
'3474427698'
```